# How to filter events based on select value on FullCalendar V5?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I've just tried FullCalendar plugin for the first time, so i went with Version 5.

I just want to filter visible events by selecting value in a select dropdown.

I can't seem to find a simple and efficient way to do this with V5.

Many ressources that i found on internet talk about using rererenderEvents or refetchEvents but it refers to previous version of plugin and this is not working here.

I found a workaround by looping through the events and changing the visibility with setProp, but it doesn't look very good. I have a lot of events and the for loop takes several seconds (code in comment in snippet)

Thank you very much for your advice and help

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  let currentDayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

  let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    firstDay: 1,
    hiddenDays: [ 0, 6 ],
    slotMinTime: '07:00',
    slotMaxTime: '20:00',
        allDaySlot: false,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,today,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek'
    },
    views: {
      timeGridWeek: {
        type: 'timeGrid',
        duration: { days: 2 },
        buttonText: '2 day'
      }
    },
   events: [{
      "title": "Marc",
      "start": currentDayDate + " 07:30",
      "end": currentDayDate + " 08:30",
      "userId": "1"
    }, {
      "title": "Tom",
      "start": currentDayDate + " 09:30",
      "end": currentDayDate + " 10:30",
      "userId": "2"
    }, {
      "title": "David",
      "start": currentDayDate + " 11:30",
      "end": currentDayDate + " 12:30",
      "userId": "3"
    }]
});
  calendar.render();
  
//  $( document ).ready(function() {
//   $('#selector').on('change',function(){            
//     var events = calendar.getEvents();
//     for (var i = events.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
//       if ($("#selector").val() == events[i].extendedProps.userId || $("#selector").val() == "all") {
//         events[i].setProp("display", "block");
//       }
//       else {
//         events[i].setProp("display", "none");
//       }
//     }
//   });
// });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">Marc</option>
  <option value="2">Tom</option>
  <option value="3">David</option>
</select>
<div id="calendar">

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to approach filtering with fullCalendar:

1. Filter events out as they are rendered
2. Filter the data at source, before it arrives in fullCalendar.

The approach you've seen for previous versions of fullCalendar filtering the events are they are rendered is still applicable - and that's what I'll demonstrate here. However because there's no `rerenderEvents` equivalent in v5, you need to use `refetchEvents` to make fullCalendar fetch and draw the events again. The `render` function also won't achieve it.

However, `refetchEvents` won't work unless you have a dynamic event source. Currently you have a static list of events. Consequently there's

Therefore I've written a version with a nominal [function-based](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) event source - it returns the exact same events every time, but in practice of course you wouldn't do that - you'd write code to make it request/generate a dynamic set of events based on the dates supplied, or alternativey you'd use a [JSON event source](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) where the event data is fetched directly from a URL, and the server controls what is returned.

Also in v5 the `eventRender` callback is replaced by the [event render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) - for our purpose the `eventDidMount` callback will be suitable for what we want to do. You can filter each event out as it's rendered (as opposed to your example code where you tried to fetch all the events and update their properties.)

N.B. I haven't used jQuery at all here, but of course you're welcome to use it wherever you want to in place of the native DOM functions.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  let currentDayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  let selector = document.querySelector("#selector");
  let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    firstDay: 1,
    hiddenDays: [0, 6],
    slotMinTime: '07:00',
    slotMaxTime: '20:00',
    allDaySlot: false,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,today,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek'
    },
    views: {
      timeGridWeek: {
        type: 'timeGrid',
        duration: {
          days: 2
        },
        buttonText: '2 day'
      }
    },
    eventDidMount: function(arg) {
      let val = selector.value;
      if (!(val == arg.event.extendedProps.userId || val == "all")) {
        arg.el.style.display = "none";
      }
    },
    events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
      successCallback([{
        "title": "Marc",
        "start": currentDayDate + " 07:30",
        "end": currentDayDate + " 08:30",
        "userId": "1"
      }, {
        "title": "Tom",
        "start": currentDayDate + " 09:30",
        "end": currentDayDate + " 10:30",
        "userId": "2"
      }, {
        "title": "David",
        "start": currentDayDate + " 11:30",
        "end": currentDayDate + " 12:30",
        "userId": "3"
      }]);
    }
  });
  calendar.render();

  selector.addEventListener('change', function() {
    calendar.refetchEvents();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="1">Marc</option>
  <option value="2">Tom</option>
  <option value="3">David</option>
</select>
<div id="calendar">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add with checkbox and dropdown in this demo? @ADyson

Comment: @SarveshPatel What do you mean? A checkbox and drop-down to do what, exactly? The demo already has a dropdown...do you want a different one? P.S. In general if you have a new problem, you should ask a new Stackoverflow question about it, showing what you've tried in terms of implementing your requirements, and where you're stuck. I'm not going to change this demo to do something which isn't solving the problem stated in the original question here.

Comment: thanks, Yes I have the new requirement and yes I can ask the new questions but StackOverflow is not permitted to ask questions. That is why I asked you. Please check this What I asking http://prntscr.com/22ypz7o.

Comment: Actually, both separate working but I want to combine and work as a filter with all. that is my question.

Comment: That's still too vague. And "I want" isn't a question, anyway.  If you have a question, press the Ask Question button and write out a full question, with a proper specification for what you want, and include your attempts to solve it, and a description of what goes wrong when you try. Your _question_ (you'll need one of those!) should be based on the problem you're having with your implementation of the specification. You can of course provide a link to this answer in your post, for background, but that cannot be a replacement for also posting your own code, as modified by you. See also [ask].

Comment: Thanks, But I am not able to post a new question because I reached my question limit. I will try to elaborate more here. http://prntscr.com/22ys1p2

Comment: We don't answer questions via comments, sorry. Few people can see it, no-one can search the comments to find the answer in future, and no-one can vote on the question, or vote on the answers. It completely defeats the point of Stackoverflow. The idea is to build a repository of questions and answers which will be useful to _everyone_. We can't do that if you don't follow the structure of the site. We're not a personal helpdesk service. You'll need to wait until you can post questions again. Presumably you posted some poor-quality ones or something, leading to your account being restricted?

Comment: What I will say, from a brief glance at your screenshot, is that it should just be a case of adding extra properties to your events, and adding extra `if` tests into the  `eventDidMount` callback. I doubt the logic is really that complex. It should be possible to at least attempt it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240158/discussion-between-sarvesh-patel-and-adyson).