# Filter events for a specific view

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm looking for a way to filter my events for the view listyear in fullcalendar V5.

I got my events by a feed and they are separated in two categories.

[image: orange and blue are different type of event]

The problem is when i display them on listyear view i got all the events and i actualy want to only display the orange one.

[image]

I didn't find any topic about that so if u have some track for me i would be grateful.

Comment: Which version of fullCalendar? Anyway, this isn't really how the views are intended to be used. The idea is that all views will display the same data, but they provide a different way of looking at it - e.g. different layout, different time range, but the information is the same. Otherwise the users might be confused why an event shows up in one place but not another, and might assume there is no event at a certain time, when actually there is. Why do you want the event list to be different just in one particular view?

Comment: Thanks for answering. The idea is that my event are related to classes from a school and the blue one is event displayed for every teachers and the orange one is for the teacher itself (of the session) and i want to use the listyear view for displaying only the event of the teacher itself separate from the other type of event. I think i need to catch the change of view from a method but i couldn't find it while doing my research.

Comment: But why do that only in that specific view? Do only certain teachers use the listYear view, or something? Surely a better approach would simply be to have a filter which can show or hide certain types of events, regardless of which view is being used.

Comment: It's a request from them to use that type of view certainly because a list is an easier way to figure wich event you have in the following weeks. But maybe it's possible to trigger a script that will erase the other events by clicking on the listyear view button ?

Comment: That's not so easy, to be honest. It just isn't designed like that. As I say, a better approach would be to apply a general filtering mechanism, to filter out specific types of events, indepdently from the view being used.

Comment: If you're using fullCalendar 5, then you may find this post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69881510/how-to-filter-events-based-on-select-value-on-fullcalendar-v5